# yii get listview id on click?

Tags: php, html, yii2

i am trying to get the id of list that is selected in a listview in yii2 assign it to a label in the page. the list displays well but how do i select one data this is the listview below and assign it to and i and echo it.

index.php

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use app\models\MyProfile;
use app\models\LikeDiscussion;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use common\models\Topic;
use common\models\Comment;
use common\models\Candidate;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>

                <?php

         $query = Topic::find()->all();
            $dataArr = array();
          foreach ($query as $detail) {
            $dataArr[] = array(
                'id' => $detail->id,
                'created' => $detail->created,
                'creator' => $detail->creator,
                 'views' => $detail->views
            );
          }
          $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $dataArr,
                'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
                ],
                'sort' => [
                    'attributes' => ['views'=>SORT_ASC]
                ],
            ]);
?>  
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'countries']) ?>
         <?=  ListView::widget([
             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
             'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'comment-item'],
             'itemView' => 'indexadapter',

        ]);

            ?>
<h5> <?php echo id; ?>  </h5>
<div id="footer">
    <footer class="row">
    <p class="back-top floatright">
        <a href="#top"><span></span></a>
    </p>
                <div class="two mobile-one columns">
                <a href="#" class="postfix button expand">GO</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

this is the indexadapter.php page

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;

//var_dump($model);exit;
?>


    <div class="gravatar">
                <img src="images/gravatar.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <h5><?php echo $model['topic']; ?>
            </h5>

            <p>
            <h5>
            <span class="commentdate">
                <?php echo $model['created']. "by" .$model['creator']; ?>
            </span>
            </h5>
        </p>
            <hr>
```

Comment: if you have found  a way to solve your question .. please post it so the communty can use it..

Answer (score 1):

i just edited the indexadapter class. created a href link

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier;

//var_dump($model);exit;
?>


    <div class="gravatar" >
                <img src="images/gravatar.png" alt="" >
            </div>
            <h5><?php echo $model['topic']; ?>
            </h5>
            <a href="<?php echo $model['topic']; ?>">link</a>
            <p>
            <h5>
            <span class="commentdate">
                <?php echo $model['created']. "by" .$model['creator']; ?>
            </span>
            </h5>
        </p>
            <hr>
```